# Is Identity library is must in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using self-implemented Authentication class for Logins and Authentication in my ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. I found out several video tutorials and posts which use Identity library in their implementation. As i'm new to MVC 5. Is it necessary to use Identity library for authentication part of development? And what are the consequences if I use self-implemented methods for authentication part of my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use the Identity libraries comes with asp.net. Implementing your own authentication mechanism is not a trivial task. Especially getting the crypto/hashing algorithms right. One consequence of bad library implementation is in case of a data breach you put all of your user passwords exposed. Some of which might be the same password they used for their bank account.